# generate a lists of list based on the elements of a list

Tags: python, list

So I have a list1 and a list_of_list1, for this example I will simplify it to:

```
list1=['a','cs','akdf']
list_of_list1=[['cs','kdddd','wwww'],['a','papa','lsl'],['jdk','asas'],['akdf', 'ffff','pep8']]
```

I would like to check if the elements in list1 are in any of the list_of_list1
then append that sublist to a new list called list_with_structures.

The desired output would be:

```
[['a','papa','lsl'],['cs','kdddd','wwww'],['akdf', 'ffff','pep8']]
```

Here is my code:

```
list_with_structures=[]
for sublist in list_of_list1:
    for valores in list1:
        if valores in sublist:
            list_with_structures.append(sublist)
            break
list_with_structures
```

NOTE: The nº of elements in list1 is much greater than the lists in list_of_list1

Comment: Your code already appears to do what you want, with the caveat that the desired output is slightly out of order: `[['cs', 'kdddd', 'wwww'], ['a', 'papa', 'lsl'], ['akdf', 'ffff', 'pep8']]`. Did it not work for you?

Comment: It did not worked because it did not generated the whole list of sublists

Comment: Are you only showing a portion of the lists of lists? Because as it stands, your code performs exactly what you want it to with the specified lists and lists_of_lists

Comment: Sorry I simplified the code because the list is massive

Comment: Ok. Maybe get rid of the break command - that could terminate the loop prematurely before everything has been checked.

Comment: Thank you! You can also mark as accepted answer if you like :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `break` command was prematurely stopping your list checking from iterating through list1.

To reconfigure your code:

```
for sublist in list_of_list1:
    for valores in list1:
        if valores in sublist:
            list_with_structures.append(sublist)
```

For readability, I'd recommend:

```
for item in list1:
    for sublist in list_of_list1:
        if item in sublist:
            list_with_structures.append(sublist)
```

Comment: Note you can also do this elegantly with a list comprehension: `[sublist for item in list1 for sublist in list_of_list1 if item in sublist]`